# Parsing df command output with awk

Tags: awk

How can I store the first line of output to print as a header after matching all lines that start with `/dev/nvme`?

Right now I'm calling `df` twice, but I would like to do it in one pass with awk.

```
df -h | grep '^Filesystem' && df -h | grep '^/dev/nvme'
```

Desired results would be:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p2  ...
/dev/nvme0n1p1 ...
```

Comment: `df -h | awk 'NR==1 || /^\/dev\/nvme*/'`

Comment: `df` != `du`, for the record.  But why not provide the paths you're checking to `df` directly:  `df -h /dev/nvme*`

Comment: ... except you don't need/want the `*` (it's not a glob)

Comment: @jasonwryan the statement `NR==1 || /^\/dev\/nvme*/` is tested against every line correct? (if total number of records =1 or line starts with /dev/nvme)

Comment: Yes, awk reads every line of input, unless instructed otherwise. It's default action is to print, so it prints the first line and any that match the pattern.

Comment: `grep` can match multiple patterns in one pass, but you apparently don't want that

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 `grep '^Filesystem\|^/dev/nvme'` I wanted to do it with awk. One day ill be like u

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted by others:

```
df -Ph | awk 'NR == 1 || $0 ~ "^/dev/nvme"'
```

Alternatively, Linux `df` allows you to specify the device file on the command line:

```
df -x devtmpfs -Ph /dev/nvme*
```

The `-x devtmpfs` is to prevent the `/dev` filesystem from showing up when a matching device is not mounted.

The `-P` option guarantees that `df` won't break a line even if one of the columns is wide.

The advantage with the second method is that `df` will space the columns appropriately for the output.

Comment: I tried `df -h /dev/nvme*` and as you mentioned, it showed 2 /dev filesystem entries.

Comment: @jes516 - You missed the `-x devtmpfs` part

Comment: Works perfect with `-x devtmpfs`